# Running LSTM on keras.io for multivariable time-series data (LONG)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I have a data-set of quarterly Economic variables and I want to try and predict some binary variable (government of the day) by utilising an `LSTM` framework.

The data-set would look something like:

```
Date           X1   X2   X3   X4    X5  Y1
------------------------------------------
01-Jan-1954    0.1  2.4  5.5  0.66  0.2  1
01-April-1954  0.3  2.0  5.0  0.67  0.4  1
                    .
                    .
                    .
01-July-2016   0.4  5.0  1.0  0.88  0.4  0
```

that is: I want to use `X1-X5` in periods `0,...,t` to be able to predict `Y1` in period `t+1`.

I have got thus far using the sequential model...

```
import pandas as pd  
from random import random
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, merge 
import scipy
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, merge

Macro=pd.read_csv('MACROUS2.csv')
Macro=Macro.ix[:,Macro.columns!= 'DATE']    

'''
The model architecture is made to pull in 
'''

def _load_data(Macro, n_prev = 16):  
    """
    data should be pd.DataFrame()
    """

    docX, docY = [], []
    for i in range(len(Macro)-n_prev):
        docX.append(Macro.iloc[i:i+n_prev].as_matrix())
        docY.append(Macro.iloc[i+n_prev].as_matrix())
    alsX = np.array(docX)
    alsY = np.array(docY)

    return alsX, alsY

def train_test_split(df, test_size=0.1):  
    """
    This just splits data to training and testing parts
    """
    ntrn = round(len(df) * (1 - test_size))

    X_train, y_train = _load_data(df.iloc[0:ntrn])
    X_test, y_test = _load_data(df.iloc[ntrn:])


  return (X_train, y_train[:][0]), (X_test, y_test[:][0])
 (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = train_test_split(Macro)
```

my data has the shape:

```
X_train has shape:  (209, 16, 6)
y_train has shape:  (6,)
X_test has shape:  (9, 16, 6)
y_test has shape:  (6,)
```

I had it this shape to reflect a single 'time piece' being 16 quarters (4 years).

I define the architecture in the following way:

```
in_neurons = np.shape(X_train)[2]   
out_neurons = np.shape(y_train)[0]
hidden_neurons = 20

model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=hidden_neurons, input_dim=in_neurons, return_sequences=False)) 
model.add(Dense(output_dim=out_neurons, input_dim=hidden_neurons))
model.add(Activation("linear"))  
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
```

However, upon trying to train the model I encounter some problems:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = train_test_split(Macro)  # retrieve data
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=450, nb_epoch=1, validation_split=0.05)  

predicted = model.predict(X_test)  
rmse = np.sqrt(((predicted - y_test) ** 2).mean(axis=0))
```

I get the following exception:

```
Error when checking model target: expected activation_1 to have shape (None, 6) but got array with shape (6, 1)
```

I am quite new to making RNN's so excuse me if I am ignorant in my questions or how I attempted this problem. Any advice on how to continue and to resolve this Exception would be greatly appreciated!

credit to http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/ as a major source for how I tried to do this.

Comment: @Marcin Mozejko- thank you for update.